# Linux operating system not recognised by vmware player-Mint, Fedora, Red Hat

Tags: linux, download, fedora, redhat, linux-mint

I am currently trying to download a few server versions of Linux operating systems in order to compare which is best in terms of memory usage etc. I am running these off of the vmware program and have managed to download the ubuntu server and desktop ok. However, I cannot seem to find any version of red hat that isn't free, or indeed the server versions of Mint and Fedora. I have managed to download Fedora only to discover it was the desktop version which doesn't have a terminal and any time I have downloaded a version of Mint(any version at all), when I run it on vmware player, it tells me that vmware player does not recognise the operating system and then nothing else happens. I have been sure to download the iso file for these as well but with no success.

Does anyone know then any links where I can download the servers for Mint, Fedora and Red Hat that actually work? it is very frustrating that it hasn't worked so far.

Comment: Just use [Debian](http://debian.org). It's the best. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most available ISO images will fit into Vmware. However, you can find some of the images below

http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/

Comment: I've checked some of these but they seem to be desktop based. I am only allowed to use the servers-do you know where you could download those?

Comment: This link contains server and desktop images.I am not sure which linux flavor you are looking after